# oracle query error: exact fetch return more than requested no of rows

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have two tables  `seatinfo(siid,seatno,classid,tsid)` and `booking (bookid,siid,date,status)`.

I've input parameter bookDate,v_tsId ,v_clsId. I need exactly one row (bookid) to return. This query is not working. I don't no why. How can I fix it?

```
 select bookid 
   into v_bookid 
    from booking 
   where (to_char(booking.bookdate,'dd-mon-yy'))=(to_char(bookDate,'dd-mon-yy')) 
     and status=0 
     and rownum <= 1 
     and siid in(select siid 
                   from seatinfo 
                  where tsid=v_tsId 
                   and classid= v_clsId);
```

I also tried this:

```
select bookid 
  into v_bookid 
  from booking,
       seatinfo 
 where booking.siid=seatinfo.siid 
   and (to_char(booking.bookdate,'dd-mon-yy'))=(to_char(bookDate,'dd-mon-yy')) 
   and booking.status=0 
   and rownum <= 1 
   and seatinfo.tsid=v_tsId 
   and seatinfo.classid= v_clsId;
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying that you get an "ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows" when you run both of those queries?  That seems highly unlikely since you're including the predicate `rownum <= 1`.  Can you cut and paste from a SQL*Plus session that runs just this query in a PL/SQL block and generates the error?

If you are not complaining about the error you mention in the title, and the problem is just that you're not getting the data you expect, the likely problem is that you apparently have a `bookDate` parameter that has the same name as a column in your table.  That is not going to work.  When you say

```
(to_char(booking.bookdate,'dd-mon-yy'))=(to_char(bookDate,'dd-mon-yy'))
```

you presumably mean to compare the `bookDate` column in the `booking` table against the `bookDate` parameter.  But since column names have precedence over local variables, the left-hand side of your expression is also looking at the `bookDate` column in the `booking` table.  So you're comparing a column to itself.  It would make much more sense to change the name of the parameter (to, say, `p_bookDate`) and then write

```
booking.bookDate = p_bookDate
```

or, if you want to do the comparison ignoring the time component of the dates

```
trunc( booking.bookDate ) = trunc( p_bookDate )
```

Comment: thanks Justin Cave.Yes i got  ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows" for both queries. rownum<=1 is working fine in PL/SQL.i've tried this (p_bookDate) its not working.

Comment: @AwladLiton - Also, what do you mean "`rownum <= 1` is working fine in PL/SQL"?  If it is "working", then you wouldn't be getting an error, right?  But you just said that both queries, each of which has a `rownum <= 1` clause, are generating errors.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, Justin Cave. i meant that rownum <= 1 is working fine in any simple query.